# timezone setting per virtual host

Tags: lighttpd, timezone

I am trying to test functionality related to timezone handling/conversion
during synchronization between two of my test servers (currently they are running on same mashine).

Is it possible to set up hosts so one will be running, say, by London time, and the other by Moscow?

Web applications running on both servers are written on Perl.

Comment: What are your hosts? you've given us almost no information here?

Comment: I have one lighhttpd instance serving, say, two webapps on different domain names. Is it possible configure them in a way that perl Today_And_Now call inside each app return different results (one for Moscow time, another for London time)? I need this fo testing purposes. I doesn't want to run separate VM for each app

Answer (score 1):

Generally servers have the clock set on UTC anyway, and they use the time zone information just for display. There should be no issue having virtual machines with different time zones on the same host.

Comment: I have one lighhttpd instance serving, say, two webapps on different domain names. I doesn't want to run separate VM for each app